# FID and custom feature extractor

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, torchmetrics

I would like to use a custom feature extractor to calculate FID

according to https://lightning.ai/docs/torchmetrics/stable/image/frechet_inception_distance.html I can use `nn.Module` for `feature`

What is wrong with the following code?

```py
import torch
_ = torch.manual_seed(123)
from torchmetrics.image.fid import FrechetInceptionDistance
from torchvision.models import inception_v3


net = inception_v3()
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint.pt')
net.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
net.eval()

fid = FrechetInceptionDistance(feature=net)
# generate two slightly overlapping image intensity distributions
imgs_dist1 = torch.randint(0, 200, (100, 3, 299, 299), dtype=torch.uint8)
imgs_dist2 = torch.randint(100, 255, (100, 3, 299, 299), dtype=torch.uint8)
fid.update(imgs_dist1, real=True)
fid.update(imgs_dist2, real=False)
result = fid.compute()

print(result)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 12, in <module>
    fid = FrechetInceptionDistance(feature=net)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torchmetrics/image/fid.py", line 304, in __init__
    num_features = self.inception(dummy_image).shape[-1]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py", line 166, in forward
    x, aux = self._forward(x)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py", line 105, in _forward
    x = self.Conv2d_1a_3x3(x)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py", line 405, in forward
    x = self.conv(x)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 460, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 456, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're casting your inputs to `dtype=torch.uint8`. The model expects a float tensor.

Comment: The error is from line above of the images, When I set `fid = FrechetInceptionDistance(feature=net)`  see https://github.com/Lightning-AI/torchmetrics/blob/3e5a6ea49046d90574ae25151cebfe3b1d96496d/src/torchmetrics/image/fid.py#L300